# Loading desired libraries at run-time

Tags: c++, c, header, shared-libraries

I am trying to analyze some shared libraries in Ubuntu under Intel's Vtune tool. However, since these shared libraries cannot be loaded as independent executable, I have to write a c/c++ program to load them at run time. My question is that how I can know which headers invoke which shared libraries? Is there any command or lookup table to know which header belongs to which .so file in the system??

Comment: Usually you just include the header files needed and link against these libraries stubs. Maybe you're missing to have the development packages for these libraries installed?!?

Comment: Did you consider loading these libraries dynamically using [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html)?

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ: My target is to analyze specific libraries. So, I do not have any problem with the already used headers as their corresponding libraries can be analyzed easily. The question is usage of which headers lead to loading of a certain shared library?

Comment: @ Basile Starynkevitch: I think that is what exactly i am looking for. Thanks.